# Install Textblob to Python 3.5.2

Tags: 14.04, python, text-processing

I installed Textblob as per instructions from the https://textblob.readthedocs.io website.

It's working just fine in python 2.7 but I can't get it to work on python 3.5.2. I tried to install it using various commands but it didn't work.

Comment: Still haven't figured it out. :/

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh 16.04 system, I can do this:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install -U textblob
python3 -m textblob.download_corpora
```

You'll notice a few things:

- In ubuntu, the python3 versions of things are usually named 'python3-BLAH'.
- Also, the pip binary is named `pip3`, and the python 3 interpreter is named `python3`.
- These differ from the readthedocs site, but are standard on Ubuntu.

If you just follow the instructions on the readthedocs site, you will probably get **only** the python 2 versions of things.  Maybe that is what you did, I'm not sure.